# How do you delete all indexes in elastic search using node.js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html) recommends the following function to delete a specific index:

```
client.delete({
  index: 'myindex',
  type: 'mytype',
  id: '1'
}, function (error, response) {
  // ...
});
```

Which I have adapted to:

```
client.delete({
  index: '_all'
}, function (error, response) {
  // ...
});
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
Unable to build a path with those params. Supply at least index, type, id
```

I've been searching around for a couple of hours to no avail, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The method you copied is for deleting a document, not an index. You want [this call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-delete).

Comment: @Tony Could you give an example of how that call would look in practice? I was reviewing that before, but couldn't make sense of how the actual call would look like with the desired parameters.

Comment: @Tony Nevermind, figured it out. Had to pass in the parameters as a JSON object, my bad. Not that experienced with JavaScript programming yet.

Comment: You should post your working code as an answer you can accept for completeness.

Comment: @Tony Is that okay to do? I actually feel embarrassed by the whole ordeal, but to provide my own answer and accept it... I wouldn't want the community getting mad and frowning upon me. Maybe just post the code, and not accept?

Comment: Not at all. It's fairly common. I'd be more annoyed to see a question with your comment saying, "I figured it out." and then see nothing like the countless forum posts online. =)

Answer (score 33):

So, turns out I was using the wrong method. The below should take care of deleting all the indexes.

```
client.indices.delete({
    index: '_all'
}, function(err, res) {

    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Indexes have been deleted!');
    }
});
```

You can introduce specific index names within that 'index' parameter, and you can also use '*' as an alternate to '_all'.

Comment: What about removing just based on a type?